# How to remove the dividing lines between plotted areas in MatLab?

Tags: matlab, graphics, matlab-figure

This is the graph I am intending to make:
[flight envelope](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KTfwb.jpg)

The way I coded it, it is composed of 7 different curves/lines plotted in the same graph. So, when I use the `area` function not only does each area is colored differently (a problem I "solved" with the `set (ai, 'Facecolor', [x y z])` function) but it also creates a dividing line between each area. I would like to know how to remove these lines

```
function plot_flight_envelope (aviao, const)

W = aviao.MTOW;
S = aviao.sA;
Cl_max = aviao.CL_max_asa;
b = aviao.bA;
rho = const.rho;
g = const.g;
a = 0.0820586;

%evelope de manobra
n = 0:0.001:2.5;
n1 = 0:-0.001:-1.25;
Vs = sqrt((2 * W)/(rho * S * Cl_max));                           %formula
Va = Vs * sqrt(2.5);                                             %Va == x quando y == n_max(2.5)
Vc = 2.4 * sqrt(W/S);                                            %FAR 23.335?
Vd = 1.4 * Vc;                                                   %FAR 23.335

hold on
plot ((Vs * sqrt(n)), n, 'b')                                    %plota parabola positiva
n = 1:0.001:2.5;                                                 %
a1 = area ((Vs * sqrt(n)), n)                                    %

plot (( Vs * sqrt(-1 * n1)), n1, 'b')                            %plota parabola negativa
n1 = -1:-0.001:-1.25;                                            %
a2 = area (( Vs * sqrt(-1 * n1)), n1)                            %

a3 = area ([Va, Vc], ones(1,2) *(2.5))                           %plota linhas positivas
plot ([Va, Vc], ones(1,2) *(2.5), 'b') 
a4 = area ([Vc, Vd], [2.5, 2])                                   %
plot ([Vc, Vd], [2.5, 2], 'b')
a5 = area ([Vd, Vd], [0, 2])                                     % 
plot ([Vd, Vd], [0, 2], 'b') 

a6 = area ([(Vs * sqrt(1.25)), Vc], -1 * [1.25, 1.25])           %plota linhas negativas
plot ([(Vs * sqrt(1.25)), Vc], -1 * [1.25, 1.25], 'b')
a7 = area ([Vc, Vd], -1 * [1.25, 0])                             %
plot ([Vc, Vd], -1 * [1.25, 0], 'b')

%envelope de rajada
Uc = 15.24;                                                      %FAR 23.333
Vc2 = 0:0.01:Vc;                                                    
Ud = 7.62;                                                       %FAR 23.333
Vd2 = 0:0.01:Vd;
mi = 2 * (W / (S * g)) / (rho * (S / b) * a);                    %formula
K = (0.88 * mi) / (5.3 + mi);                                    %formula
ncp = calcula_n (const, Uc, Vc2, +1, K, W, S);
ncn = calcula_n (const, Uc, Vc2, -1, K, W, S);
ndp = calcula_n (const, Ud, Vd2, +1, K, W, S);
ndn = calcula_n (const, Ud, Vd2, -1, K, W, S);

plot (Vc2, ncp, 'r')
plot (Vc2, ncn, 'r')
plot (Vd2, ndp, 'r')
plot (Vd2, ndn, 'r')

plot ([max(Vc2), max(Vd2)], [max(ncp), max(ndp)], 'r')
plot ([max(Vc2), max(Vd2)], [min(ncn), min(ndn)], 'r')

set(a1,'FaceColor',[0.75 0.75 0]);
set(a2,'FaceColor',[0.75 0.75 0]);
set(a3,'FaceColor',[0.75 0.75 0]);
set(a4,'FaceColor',[0.75 0.75 0]);
set(a5,'FaceColor',[0.75 0.75 0]);
set(a6,'FaceColor',[0.75 0.75 0]);
set(a7,'FaceColor',[0.75 0.75 0]);



    function n = calcula_n (const, U, V, coef, K, W, S)
        n = 1 + (coef * (rho * V * a * K * U) / (2 * W / S));
    end

grid
hold off
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the **edge** colour of your areas:

```
set (ai, 'Edgecolor', [x y z])
```